# When is every nonzero endomorphism of a right $R$-module $M$ onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $M$ any right $R$-module. I know that $M$ is called **co-Hopfian** if every monomorphism $\text{End}(M)$ is onto.

My question is: When is every nonzero endomorphism $f\in \text{End}(M)$ (either injective or not) is onto?. Is there a name for such modules?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to exclude trivial cases in some sense? Because there's always the zero endomorphism, which of course is never onto unless the module is trivial.

Comment: Oh excuse me. I edited my question. Does it make sense now?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial answer:

1. Every such module is indecomposable, because the projection onto a nontrivial direct summand gives a non-surjective endomorphism.
2. Conversely, every simple module has this property, because by Schur's lemma, every endomorphism of a simple module is either zero or an isomorphism.
3. More generally, a module whose endomorphism ring is a division ring (meaning every nonzero endomorphism is an isomorphism) is called a *brick*; see [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377497/for-what-modules-is-the-endomorphism-ring-a-division-ring) for some more discussion of these. A non-simple example is $\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

So we have a chain of inclusions
$$\{\text{simple modules}\} \subset \{\text{bricks}\} \subseteq \{\text{your modules}\} \subseteq \{\text{indecomposables}\}.$$
I don't know if there's a name for the class of modules such that every nonzero endomorphism is surjective (but not necessarily bijective).

Comment: Apologies, I wrote a comment that I retracted almost instantly because it was polluted by my thinking of $End(R_R)$ rather than $End(M_R)$.